# Can I update a column I created to show the day of the week from an existing date column in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I created a column called DayofWeek, and I am attempting to update it and insert that day of the week for the date that is in an existing column called ActivityDate.

```
##Used to create the column
ALTER TABLE `bellabeat-case-study-2-376122.fitbit_data.daily_activity`
ADD COLUMN DayofWeek String;
```

```
##This query brings up the day of the week
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE('%A', ActivityDate) AS DayofWeek
FROM
  `bellabeat-case-study-2-376122.fitbit_data.daily_activity`
```

I attempted to update the DayofWeek column but I couldn't come up with a query that didn't give me any errors.

Answer (score 0):

This should update aö rows.

The qiestion remains do you need it really. as you could always select it in your query

```
UPDATE   `bellabeat-case-study-2-376122.fitbit_data.daily_activity`
SET DayofWeek  = FORMAT_DATE('%A', ActivityDate)
```